# Javascript not loading from local drive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm overlooking the obvious...Modifying an index page on local hard drive before uploading it to server. And the javascript is not loading. This doesn't work:

```
file:///Users/meltemi/Sites/mysite/index.html
```

But, when page is uploaded and served from Apache then the javascript works:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.html
```

Site directories are identical both locally and on remote server. I have tried this with Safari 5.0.5 & Firefox 4.0.

code excerpts, though I don't believe it's a code issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="galleria/galleria-1.2.3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<header class="group">
    <div id="header-inner">
        <nav class="group">
                  ...
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<hr />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (Galleria) { $("body").text('Galleria works') }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you running a web server?

Comment: I'm on a Mac...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path including the drive. The `file:` part is unnecessary.

> C:/Users/meltemi/Sites/mysite/javascriptfile.js

or *nix:

> /Users/meltemi/Sites/mysite/javascriptfile.js

Ideally you'll develop in a web environment and then can use a path relative the webroot which will be the same regardless of whether the site is local or on the live server:

> /javascripts/javascriptfile.js

Comment: Using `/Users/meltemi/Sites/mysite/javascriptfile.js` resolves to `file:///Users/meltemi/Sites/mysite/javascriptfile.js` on a Mac at least.

Comment: Ah. i see what you're talking about... the `http:` got truncated at some point in my `script src` for jQuery. Dunno why it would work when being served by Apache?!? perhaps jQuery was cached?!? Ah well, silly mistake. Thanks for help!